# PDO Named parameters inside JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo, prepared-statement

I have data that should be escaped inside a JSON formatted string, so I'm using PDO's named parameters and PDO::Prepare to bind them.
Because JSON with it's apostrophes causes errors in the MySQL query, i have to use single quotes around it - although this causes the PDO::Prepare to ignore the named parameters inside the JSON, so it fails with `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined`.

Any ideas how to work around this?

```
function send($_data) {
  global $_SESSION;
  global $dbApi;

  #These are temporary debug variables:
  $_SESSION['room_id'] = 1;
  $id = 124;

  $json  = '"' . $id . '": {"user_id": ":email","data": ":data"}';
  $query  = "UPDATE `room_index` " . 
            "SET `data` = JSON_ARRAY_INSERT(`data`, '$[0]', '" . $json . "') " .
            "WHERE `id` = :room_id";

  $dbApi->query($query, array(':email' => $_SESSION['email'],
                              ':data' => $_data,
                              ':room_id' => $_SESSION['room_id']));
}
```

To explain the code a bit, `:email` (`$_SESSION['email']`) doesn't have to be a parameter, but it's cleaner this way. The main issue is `:data` (`$_data`) - that is user input straight from a `textarea` via JS.

`$dbApi` is a class with a proper `query` function, that looks like this:

```
function query($_query, $_params = array()) {
  global $_DB; # <- Database connection object

  $query = $_DB->prepare($_query);

  if (! $query)
    echo $_DB->errorInfo();
  try {
    $query->execute($_params);
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    die( $e->getMessage() );
  }

  return $query;
}
```

Comment: @LawrenceCherone As you can see, I'm using JSON_ARRAY_INSERT, which inserts this JSON into `{}` which makes it valid as far as I know. And I'm quite usure why you think my `:data` parameter doesn't exist, it isn't valid and doesn't get replaced, that's the whole issue, but It is there, in the same way as `:email` is there.

Comment: you cannot use JSON_ARRAY_INSERT like this. Edit your question asking  how to do what you need. Honestly I cannot make any idea what it should be. you are trying to overwrite the entire data or what?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks, you made me look into different inserts, apparently JSON_INSERT is much more appropriate for my situation. I also managed to fix the code using JSON_OBJECT which eliminates the need for quotes.

Comment: Just note that what you have here is a complete mess. I only hope that in your new solution you are using parameters properly

Comment: @YourCommonSense I hope so too :D I'll post an answer soon - I mean, it works properly and generates valid JSON, so I am probably doing it right. Straight from MySQL: `{"124": {"user_id": "email@email.com", "data": "asdfasdf"}, "125": {"user_id": "email@email.com", "data": "textofanothermessage"}, "126": {"user_id": "email@email.com", "data": "message3"}}`, this is what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 issues with the code.

### 1. JSON_INSERT is more appropriate.

As I'm inserting a named object into another object (the top level document), the JSON_INSERT offers such a syntax straight away

### 2. Using JSON_OBJECT instead of manually writing the JSON syntax

As my main issue was, that PDO doesn't replace single, or double quoted parameters, the solution was using JSON_OBJECT, which doesn't require double quotes as they are automatically generated later (my assumption) - but after PDO replaces the variables and also places single quotes around them.

New, tested code outputting valid JSON:

```
#Temporary, to avoid other unrelated issues
$_SESSION['room_id'] = 1;
$_SESSION['email'] = 'email@email.com';
$id = 123;

$json  = 'JSON_OBJECT("user_id", :email, "data", :data)';
$query  = "UPDATE `room_index` " . 
          "SET `data` = JSON_INSERT(`data`, :id, $json) " .
          "WHERE `id` = :room_id";

$dbApi->query($query, [':id' => "$." . $id,
                       ':email' => $_SESSION['email'],
                       ':data' => $_data,
                       ':room_id' => $_SESSION['room_id']]);
```

Comment: As a bonus, the double quotes from JSON are not escaped as before - making it more readable and easier to work with.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm unsure what you mean by improper (you can probably tell I'm not fully familiarized with PDO)... the only variable should be the static `$json`, which is there just for readability.

Comment: My mistake I overlooked it.

Comment: @YourCommonSense No worries :) You nearly had me convinced though :D Also, even If I wanted, I couldn't write the `$json` variable as a parameter, because then the parameters inside it wouldn't get replaced.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Also thanks, your first comment got me to look up JSON_ARRAY_INSERT again, and notice the other function - leading me to my solution.